# Team Explorer 2010 Command Line syntax - do commands resemble any other major SCCM?

Tags: tfs, team-explorer

I can't find any comparisons online, and I'm not familiar with any major source control providers except for VSS/TFS. Does the usage of the new Team Foundation 2010 Command-line Client (Team Explorer Everywhere cross-platform command line) resemble any other major systems?

What I mean is - do the switches you'd use to run it resemble Subversion? CVS? Some other standard Microsoft made up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK The switches are pretty much what the developers at Microsoft made up as they were making the tool (just as the switches for the other SCM tools were pretty much what those developers came up with at the time).  The TFS ones are documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc31bk2e(v=VS.100).aspx

Any reason for asking?

Comment: We've been using TFS since 2005, and now that there are command line tools, I'm trying to move our non-Windows developers to use TFS as well. They don't currently have any source control, but their partial to Subversion, so I was hoping there was a common command-line standard that I could mention - "Hey, if you're familiar with Subversion, then this command line tool will be no big deal to start using." Just as extra encouragement, I suppose.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  TFS has had command line tools (tf) since 2005.  The Cross platform command line that comes with Team Explorer Everywhere 2010 (the product that Microsoft just shipped and the one that I work on) is new.  It's commands are designed to be syntacticly the same as the .NET version of the command line.

SubVersion users new to TFS typically need to get used to the new terminology - i.e. "tf get" to download files, "tf checkout" to edit which is very different to SVN.

Comment: Thanks - that answers my question. Since I'm not familiar with the command line versions of any major tools, I was at a loss. Excellent work on Teamprise, BTW - it's an outstanding product, and I'm glad to see Microsoft recognized that!